# Parsing WSDL (WSDL URL) through Java

Tags: java, wsdl

Is there a way to list the webservices and their parameters including optional or mandatory from a WSDL URL using java (J2SE) ?

Sample Input :
https://com.provider.soap/services/travel?WSDL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [wsdl4j](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl4j/) its the reference implementation of [Java API for WSDL](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jwsdl-1.2-mrel2-oth-JSpec/). It allows you to parse (read) or write WSDL files.